# Django ORM SELECT with join

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

[image: ERR]

Models in django:

```
class Key(models.Model):
    id     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    name   = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Record(models.Model):
    id         = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    project_id = models.IntegerField()
    name       = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Value(models.Model):
    id        = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=True)
    record    = models.ForeignKey(Record)
    key       = models.ForeignKey(Key)
    value     = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I need to select from DB this data:

```
NAME (from record)
and fields related with this record
[NAME (from key), VALUE (from value)]
[NAME (from key), VALUE (from value)]
[...]
```

May I use django ORM to make this selection? (for example in SQL select looks like this)

```
SELECT
    `keeper_record`.`id` AS `record_id`,
    `keeper_record`.`name` AS `name`,
    `keeper_record`.`desc` AS `desc`,
    `keeper_key`.`name` AS `key_name`,
    `keeper_key`.`desc` AS `key_desc`,
    `keeper_value`.`value` AS `value_value`
FROM `keeper_record`
JOIN `keeper_value` ON `keeper_record`.`id` = `keeper_value`.`record_id`
JOIN `keeper_key` ON `keeper_key`.`id` = `keeper_value`.`key_id`
WHERE record_id = id
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following selects the values related to particular record id. You can then follow the foreign keys to get the related record and key. Using [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) minimises database lookups.

```
# Select all values related to a record in your view
record = Record.objects.get(pk=record_id)
values = Value.objects.filter(record=record).select_related()

# In your template
{% for value in values %}
{{ value.record.name }} - {{ value.key.name }} - {{ value.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

## Selecting more that one record

In your sql, you had `WHERE record_id = 1`, so I showed how to get all the values for a particular record. You could also select the values for more that one record in one query.

```
# filter all records which belong to the project with `project_id=1`
records = Record.objects.filter(project_id=1)
# select all values that belong to these records
values = Value.objects.filter(record__in=records).select_related().order_by('record')
```

Comment: I have rightly understood, that for each record need one additional query to select values, and if i want select all (or few) records i need select values in a loop?

Comment: I've updated the answer for selecting more than one record. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Should be relatively straightforward, since you already have the foreign keys tied together.

```
Record.objects.select_related().filter(id = variable_that_stores_id)
```

You can combine that with [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) to limit the fields that you want to bring back.

Comment: `select_related` won't work here, because it does not follow the foreign key 'backwards'.

Comment: I see. It appears the question has changed a bit since my post, but regardless it was either incorrect or incomplete.